# Is there a single method to combine Bluebird's `then` and `catch` functionality?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Given, I have some code like this:

```
// code bits to be executed
var X = ...;
var pre = ...;
var success = ...;
var error = ...;
var post = ...;
```

I would run it with Bluebird like this:

```
X
.then(function(val) {
    pre(val);
    success(val);
    post(val);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    pre();
    error(err);
    post();
});
```

I am looking for something simpler (in that, I can define less `function`s), along the lines of:

```
X
.complete(function(err, val) {
    pre(val);
    if (err) {
        error(err);
    }
    else {
        success(val);
    }
    post(val);
});
```

Note that I cannot make use of `finally`, since it has no arguments, neither `err` nor `val`.
Also note that `val` is assumed to be `null` or `undefined` in case of an error.

PS: The more I think about it, the more I am feeling that going [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) might fix the verbosity issue, while also keeping things neat and clean (keep the `if` out and keep things "chainable")...

Comment: @torazaburo: `then` doesn't do what the OP clearly asked for. (`nodeify` does.) Perhaps *you* should read the documentation. ;-) (Poking fun there -- RTFM is usually not useful, even as a comment, unless accompanied by specifics about what they'll see there that's relevant.)

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes you can

You can step out of a promise chain back to callback land with `nodeify` that takes a node err-back like:

```
.nodeify(function(err, val) {
    pre(val);
    if (err) {
        error(err);
    }
    else {
        success(val);
    }
    post(val);
});
```

This is useful for code that needs to expose a node errback like interface.

#### But you probably shouldn't

However, I don't think that using `.nodeify` is a very good idea here- instead you can do:

```
.finally(pre) // you always need this
.then(success, error) // call success and error and recover
.then(post); // post, this requires that `success` also returns val
```

In general, you *don't* want to have a success/fail function - this is called [The `.then(success, fail)` anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern) and indicates you should consider restructuring your code to embrace promises.

#### Returning promises

In general, instead of taking success and error callbacks like in your example you can return the promise - so if your function was:

```
function doStuff(success, error){
    x().then(moreStuff).then(success, error)
}
```

And you used it like: `doStuff(success, error)`

You can write it as:

```
function doStuff(){
    return x().then(moreStuff)
}
```

And then use it like `doStuff().then(...)` which allows for easier chaining, aggregation and manipulation of the promise.

#### The disposer pattern

A common pattern for pre/post is the *disposer* pattern - for example "pre" is open a database connection and "post" is close the database connection. This can be expressed as:

```
function withHandle(fn){
    var handle;
    return pre().then(function(resource){ // obtain the resource
       handle = resource; // keep a handle
       return resource;
    }).
    then(fn). // run the actual code for that resource
    finally(function(){
       return handle.close(); // close the resource
    });
}
```

And then used like:

```
withHandle(function(handle){
     return handle.query("Give me the first user"); 
}).then(function(result){
    // access result here, the handle is closed, can attach `catch`
});
```

Comment: Is the `finally` callback called before the `then` callback? Also, why do you not need `catch`?

Comment: @Domi `then` takes a second parameter for the error handler - the difference between `.then(..).catch(...)` and `.then(.., ..)` is that if the code in the then success handler throws the catch runs but in `then(.., ..)` they are separate. The `finally` code is called after all previous actions have completed (either successfully or not) and before the next ones are.

Comment: Thanks for all the catches @T.J.Crowder let me know if you spot anything else.

Comment: If the `finally` code is called after all previous actions, shouldn't it be used for `post` rather than `pre`?

Comment: @Domi X is already a promise - it happens when X is `finally` done. You can put the `post` in a finally too if you'd like it depends on what you'd like your return value to be - in the current code it's whatever post returns and if you put it in `finally` it's whatever `then` returns on success, error

Comment: Under "Returning promises", how does `x.then(...)` substitute for `x().then(...)`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you're very welcome to correct obvious mistakes in my answers as you read them - I write most of my answers' code in browser and these things happen every now and then :)

Comment: OK Benjamin, at such time that I'm 100% confident, that's what I will do. Meanwhile I will err on the side of caution.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 oh common we've been having this back and forth on promise questions for half a year now - I'm pretty sure you understand promises pretty well :) By all means when you see something wrong don't hesitate and just edit it. I or you can always revert it if it turns out wrong.